# Why is it that when I use a for loop in C, it is printing my text infinitely many times? (I am a beginner)

Tags: c

I have created a series of for loops but for some reason, I keep on getting infinitely many #'s as my output. I'm not really sure why this is happening. I am a beginner to programming and I am a little confused. My code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 0; x = -1 * i + (h - 1))
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < h + 1; y = i + 2)
    {
        printf("#");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

The output I'm trying to get is the following:

```
    ##\n
   ###\n
  ####\n
 #####\n
######\n
```

If someone can help me, I would be extremely grateful :)

Thanks

Comment: `for (int x = 0; x < 0; x = -1 * i + (h - 1))` - what do you expect/hope this to do?

Comment: Your code does not show what `h` is.  I am assuming 5?

Comment: This is a fragment of a program. You didn't show the input for that output. In terms of answering why it doesn't meet your expectations, you don't say why you think it should do that. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: I was hoping that that would add spaces so that my "pyramid" would be aligned to the right-hand side. Also I forgot to mention this but earlier on in my code, I specified that h refers to the height that the user inputs.

Comment: Look at the pattern - every line is the same length.  So, you can use just one internal loop whose bodys print either a space or hash, depending on whether its index is greter than 'lastSpacePos'.  You can init  'lastSpacePos' to 4 and decrement it in the outer loop so each line gets less spaces and more hashes.

Comment: [mcve]. Also please edit posts, don't clarify in comments. PS To "notify" a particular non-poster commenter when there is more than one use @username.

Comment: `x < 0` as the loop condition means it will fail before even entering the loop once, since `0 < 0` is false

Comment: I changed it to x <= 0 but that makes the spaces infinite....

Comment: In both inner loops you set `x` (or `y`) to the same value in each iteration. That is why the loops are infinite

Comment: Hi. It is evident that you have no idea what you're doing. So read how for works & a lot of examples then ask a specific question with MCVE about one loop that you are stuck with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third for loop you have `for (int y = 0; y < h + 1; y = i + 2)` the increment statement `y = i + 2` resets the loop variable `y` after each run through the body to the same value, and if this value is smaller than `h` you get an infinite loop.

You could try this:

```
int h = 7;
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < h - i; x++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    } 

    for (int y = -2; y < i; y++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

This produces:

```
       ##                                                                                                                      
      ###                                                                                                                      
     ####                                                                                                                      
    #####                                                                                                                      
   ######                                                                                                                      
  #######                                                                                                                      
 ########
```

Edit: To shift the triangle of `#` 1 space to the left the second loop needs to be changed to

```
for (x = 0; x < h - i - 1; x++)
{
    printf(" ");
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way in which it doesn't reset every time?

Comment: Hm not sure if this does exactly what you want but you could try `for (int y = 0; y < h + 1; y += i + 2)` (note the `+=`)

Comment: @HighlightPeak btw the same problem is in the second loop, you always set x to the same value after each iteration

Comment: Hi thanks for the edit! The code works perfectly except for one little problem. The output is: (space)########. Is there a way in which you can remove the space?

Comment: Yes, use `for (x = 0; x < h - i - 1; x++)` in the first loop

Answer (score 1):

The loop printing the spaces will never execute - you initialise `x` to 0, then loop *while* `x < 0` which is immediately false.

The loop printing `'#'` never exits because `y` is not modified in the loop `y = i + 2` will not advance `y` - it will simply assign it the value `2` indefinitely.  You in fact have a similar problem in the previous `x` loop, bit it never gets that far.

The above can most easily be discovered by using a debugger and stepping the code rather than posting questions on SO.

The pattern can in fact be generated using just a single inner-loop:

```
    for( int i = 0; i < h; i++ )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < h + 1; x++ )
        {
            putchar( x < h - i - 1 ? ' ' : '#' ) ;
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
```

Or perhaps less "clever":

```
    for( int i = 0; i < h; i++ )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < h + 1; x++ )
        {
            if( x < h - i - 1 )
            {
                putchar( ' ' ) ;
            }
            else
            {
                putchar( '#' ) ;
            }
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
```

Comment: sorry...i'm very new to programming

Comment: @HighlightPeak : No need to apologise.  I wish schools and tutorials introduced the use of debuggers early on (most never do); they are as useful for learning what is going on and testing code as they are for debugging.

Comment: Nice to use an `if`; I'll give you 10 for that. What about `putchar(x < h - i ? ' ' : '#')`? Probably a bit too 'advanced' for OP, but might be nice to mention.

Comment: @meaning-matters : I am not sure what you are asking.  The first was intentionally succinct, and how I'd write it, the second was more likely to be more familiar to the OP who is clearly a novice.

Comment: Hi. So I implemented the second one into my program and it works perfectly except for one little problem. On the last line, the output is: (space)###. Is there a way in which I can remove that space?

Comment: @HighlightPeak : Yes; it printed one too many spaces on _all_ lines.  I have modified the conditional test to `x < h - i - 1` - so it switches to `#` one earlier, and the loop condition to `x < h + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that you don't change the value of your loop variables `x` and `y`, so they don't terminate normally. Your program keeps on executing the block of the second `for`-loop.

Let's have a look at the first `for`:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 0; x = -1 * i + (h - 1))
```

When this is executed, `h` and `i` are fixed and you also don't change them in the body of this `for`-loop. Let's say that `h` is `10`; `i` is `0`.

This means that it starts with `x` being `0`. It does not execute its block because `x < 0` is false.

Then the second `for`:

```
for (int y = 0; y < h + 1; y = i + 2)
```

If you work this out you'll find that after the first iteration `y` will always be `0 + 2` is `2`. The loop condition the becomes: `2 < 10 + 1` (again assuming `h` is `10`), which is always true. That means that your loop keeps on spinning `for`ever.

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < h - i; x++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    for (int y = i; y < h; y++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

I think it has one or two OBOs (Out-By-One mistake), but I'm sure you'll fix that soon enough.

Comment: I think the `h++` in the third loop is not a good idea, as the outer loop uses `i < h` as end condition

Comment: @Clifford Excuse me, I'm spending a lot of time helping someone out here and make a small mistake. I even have a kind disclaimer.

Comment: @lkriener Indeed, thank you; small late night typo. fixed.

Comment: There are plenty of people willing to post tested working code, I am not sure this is helpful given that the OP could not debug his own broken code what hope has he of debugging yours!?  And it still does not work.

Comment: @Clifford is right, the code above still prduces the wrong shape of `#`

Comment: @lkriener You're repeating my last sentence. The main thing was explaining why the loops didn't work. After that it's very easy to figure it out. SO is not a code writing service.